# Syntax error when using imported Scipy functions in Julia

Tags: optimization, scipy, syntax-error, julia, minimize

I have succesfully imported Scipy Optimize's function minimize to Julia, but when I try to use it so that I specify constraints to it:

```
julia> @pyimport scipy.optimize.minimize as so

julia> so.minimize(f, x0,
                   constraints={"type": "ineq", "fun": g},
                   options={"maxiter": 1000})
```

Julia throws an error about the curly braces:

```
ERROR: LoadError: syntax: { } vector syntax is discontinued
```

Anyone having an idea of how the minimize function could be used properly in Julia?

Answer (score 3):

I now realized that the curly brackets present dicts in Python and the Julia-version should therefore look like:

```
julia> so.minimize(objective_function, coords,
                   constraints = Dict("type" => "ineq", "fun" => g),
                   options =  Dict("maxiter" => 1000))
```

So my guess is now that even though the function comes from Scipy, the input arguments need to be Julia syntax.

Comment: The other common trap is this one: https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl#troubleshooting . Personally I prefer avoiding the `@pyimport` macro altogether and just use the `pyimport` function instead, which leads to a consistent PyCall interface in julia throughout.  (i.e. `pythonmodule[:object]` then looks consistent with `pythonobject[:attribute]`  ).